# For what values of $\alpha$ does $\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{1\over {n\log n}{(\log( \log n))^{\alpha}}}$ converge?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series

For what values of $\alpha$ does $$\sum_{n=3}^{\infty}{1\over {n\log n}{(\log( \log n))^{\alpha}}}$$ converge?

What I did is:

${1\over {n\log n}{(\log( \log n))^{\alpha}}}={2^n\over {2^n n\log 2}{(\log( n\log 2))^{\alpha}}}={1\over { n\log 2}{(\log( n\log 2))^{\alpha}}}={2^n\over { 2^n\log 2}{(\log(2^n\log 2))^{\alpha}}}={1\over { \log 2}{(\log(2^n)+\log (\log 2))^{\alpha}}}={1\over { \log 2}{(n\log2+\log (\log 2))^{\alpha}}}$.

I want to use the $p$-series test but I don't know how. I would appreciate your help.

Comment: [Integral test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence) with $u = \log\log n$ subsitution.

Comment: Alternatively: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test. Furthermore: Your question is missing a verb.

Comment: Your last form is asymptotic to $\frac1{n^\alpha\log(2)^{\alpha+1}}$. Can you apply the $p$-test now?